# Embeding minimalistic Unix OS in Java

Tags: java, emulation

I am not sure if this question makes sense and in fact I do not currently have a real problem where I need to do this, but just out of curiosity:

Is it possible to embed (emulate) a minimalistic unix like OS in a Java application ? I mean, executed in the same process than the JVM and somehow providing facilities for interacting with the host JVM ?

Why this may be interesting: Let's say that a Java application requires a hypothetical cool library that is only compatible with Unix, and that this application should be deployed in Windows. At least for quick prototyping, being able to emulate a small Unix OS in the JVM may be a good idea (?)

Note that to be useful, a solution should allow to install libraries in the emulated OS.

Answer (score 1):

If it is [possible to do it in javascript](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) running in a browser,  I think it would be also possible in Java.

Comment: not what I am looking for but it is cool, do you have idea how they do that ?

Comment: No much idea about it to be honest, all I know is that is a minimalistic Linux totally implemented in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are interesting in trying [unix4j](https://code.google.com/p/unix4j/). I am not sure if I answer your question but i hope to give you an idea. 
With unix4j you can run some linux commands.
for instance if you got a command like:
cat test.txt | grep "Tuesday" | sed "s/kilogram/kg/g" | sort 
in this program will become:
Unix4j.cat("test.txt").grep("Tuesday").sed("s/kilogram/kg/g").sort();